# How to redisplay a page in iPhone UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I've got a UIWebView which starts off with the scalesPagesToFit property set to YES. This loads up the page and scales it fine. When the user taps a button I want to turn off the scaling and show the page full size but I'm struggling to figure out how to force the page to redraw. I specifically do not want to refresh the page (ie fetch it from the server again) just redraw the page that has already been downloaded. I've tried setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay but neither of these work